# Encoding parameters values in a URL with Java

Tags: java, url, urlencode

I need to encode the parameters values in an URL. If I use following:

```
URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

for a URL like this: `http://localhost:8080/...`

it will encode "://" etc. What I need is the encoding only for the values of the parameters starting from all the URL string. So in this case:

http://localhost/?q=blah&d=blah

I want encoded only the "blah" in the 2 parameters values (for n parameters of course).

What's your best way?

Thanks

Randomize

Answer (score 5):

You're using URLEncoder in a wrong way. You're supposed to encode every parameter value separately and then assemble the url together.

For example

```
String url = "http://localhost/?q=" + URLEncoder.encode ("blah", "UTF-8") + "&d=" + URLEncoder.encode ("blah", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes I know it, the problem is that I got an URL already "done" and I have no way to change the code that generate it

Comment: Why then do you need to encode it? Does it contain non ASCII characters?

Comment: Then you'll need to build a `URL` and get the params (or split on the first `?` if you're confident of the URL's validity), split them on `&` (if you don't want that encoded), encode them, then rebuild it.

Comment: Indeed if the provided url is valid your only way is to parse it and then encode properly. But it's not an encoding, it's fixing an url.

Comment: And of course there'll be problems if some parameter value contained one of characters '?', '&', '='. You may even need to decode parameter values after successful split and then encode them as you need.

Comment: well thanks for the replies, I splitted at the first '?' for the moment. I'm not sure if it covers all the cases :) but it's simplier. Thanks guys

Comment: @AndreiLED

Do i really need to encode every parameter ? Cant i just encode everything after '?' like following.
  `String url = "http://localhost/?" + URLEncoder.encode ("q=blah&d=blah", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @DeepakGangore, no, this will not work as you probably want it to: the = and & will get encoded as well and so the server will not be able to recognize q and d as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For a URL like http://localhost/hello/sample?param=bla, you could use this (from Java's  java.net.URI class):

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "localhost", "/hello/sample", "param=bla", null);
String url = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Comment: this way you need to preassemble the query string using URLEncoder to encode special characters. And as it turns out Randomize has whole url as input, not its parts.

Comment: Well, the URL can be easily broken (split) into such parts and passed along.